# Getting the week number from a Timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, hyperion

I have a field which displays a timestamp `'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss'`. I am trying to extract the Isoweek number from this field unsuccessfully receiving a variant of error messages depending on the formula I have used.

Hi, I hope someone can assist.

I am attempting to get the IsoWeeknumber from a Timestamp. I have tried the below 3 revisions getting varying error messages.

```
to_char(to_date(Datestamp, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'iw')
to_char(trunc(Datestamp),'iw')
to_char(trunc(to_date(Datestamp),'iw'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

I have also reversed `to_char(to_date(())` with no luck.

Comment: which database?

Comment: @nbk Oracle Hyperion

Comment: What is the **data type** of column `datestamp`? Don't guess; run `describe <table_name>` and see what data type it reports for this column. Also, as an aside (but not "instead of" what I just said), you should include the error messages in your question - they provide lots of clues.

Comment: Are you sure? `hh:mi:ss` means 12-hour format, which would be ambiguous without AM/PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same format as the string (with `HH24` for a 24-hour clock, rather than `HH` or `HH12` which are for 12-hour clocks):

```sql
SELECT to_char(to_date(Datestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'IW')
FROM   table_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7ab01d7db3414f0775ba4b5cb7c68bd9)*

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can extract week number from date

```
    select to_char(to_date('01/02/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have date and time

> ```
> select to_char(to_date('01/02/2022 10:10:10','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'IW') from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/02/202210:10:10','MM/DD/YYYYHH:MI:SS'),'IW') |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 52                                                               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a2a8321bd7b491ff41c55a3494d7b1e6)*

Comment: Note, Week according to ISO-8601 `IW` is different to `WW` which gives *Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.*

Comment: thx i didn't see tha, but as solution it was still ok